# Double Summation Matrix Simplification

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to simplify the following:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} (a_i - b_j)^T(a_i -b_j)$

Where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are column vectors. I'm very new to linear algebra and don't really know where I should start. I recognize that the computation of $a_i - b_j$ is repeated in every loop and have the intuition that this could somehow be simplified further.

I know that for scalars the following is true:

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{j} a_i b_j$

My intuition says that this should somehow be possible for the expression above as well. Any help would be very appreciated , thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but here is a suggestion. Define stacked vectors $v = (a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ and $w = (b_1,b_2,...,b_n)$. Basically, stack all columns as a very long column vector. Let $1$ denote the vector of ones. With $A = v1^T-w1^t$, I think, your expression is equivalent to $\sum_{i,j} A_{i,j}^2 = \textrm{trace}(A^TA)$. If you have specific programming language in mind, I can suggest how this can be done vectorized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This may not be helpful, but...) An alternative way of expressing this is to notice that each term in the double sum is a dot product. Then
\begin{align} 
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_i - b_j)^T (a_i - b_j) &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_i - b_j) \cdot  (a_i - b_j)\\
& =\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_i\cdot a_i)  - 2( a_i\cdot b_j) + (b_j \cdot  b_j)\\
& =\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_i\cdot a_i)  - 2\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n ( a_i\cdot b_j) + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (b_j \cdot  b_j)\\
& =\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i\cdot a_i) \left(\sum_{j=1}^n 1\right)  - 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right) \cdot\left( \sum_{j=1}^n  b_j\right) + \sum_{j=1}^n (b_j \cdot  b_j)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n 1\right)\\
& =n\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i\cdot a_i)  - 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right) \cdot\left( \sum_{j=1}^n  b_j\right) + n\sum_{j=1}^n (b_j \cdot  b_j).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.